# C# Console.Writeline Placeholders for function name

Tags: c#, console.writeline

Are there any placeholders for the current function's name when using Console.Writeline()?

Comment: Are there any "magic tokens" that represent the current executing method/property name in a Console.WriteLine.

Comment: This is exactly what I meant.  I apologize for being unclear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**I believe this is what you're looking for:**

```
using System.Diagnostics;

StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
Console.WriteLine(stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name);
```

Answer (score 6):

In Reflection, you have MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod() as an option.

Comment: Probably worth adding that this can be expensive.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not as expensive as Console.WriteLine.

Comment: @zmbq - fair point - but pretty much _only_ in comparison to Console.WriteLine (which is pretty damn slow). Compared to other things you might be doing, and other forms of logging, this is probably not something you want to sprinkle around too liberally.

Comment: @Rob, Is StackFrame.GetMethod() faster?

Comment: From my very crude microbenchmark or running both 100000 times - it looks like it is `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod` is 5+ times faster (assuming you create a new instance of `StackFrame` each time. It was a fairly crude micro-benchmark though! - not to be taken too seriously!

Comment: @zmbq Is there a better method to mark current position in execution that Console.Writeline?  I'm not a big fan of doing this, but it's the only way I know to give me a sense of where execution is located.

Comment: You can use the .NET tracing abilities. Or log4net.

Comment: @zmbq are the tracing abilities significantly less expensive than console.writeline?

Answer (score 2):

See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7964/Logging-method-name-in-NET

Another (better) option for logging is [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming), using a framework such as [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you want to use reflection. However, C# 5 will include a new feature called "Caller Info Attributes" which will insert the information at compile time. See http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2012/02/c-5-caller-info-attributes.html